# how to trigger a stored property with css color change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, object

I want store the the css changes in set.up and set.down. Do i have to make it inside a anonymous function?

```
set = {
  up: $('.up').css('background-color', _config.upColor),
  down : $('.down').css('background-color', _config.downColor)
}

if(true) {
  set.up
}
```

Comment: Why the `if(true)`?. And `set` should have a `=` after it (and a `var`, if you haven't declared it): `var set = {  }`

Comment: that was typo. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup you'd be better off doing something like this:

```
var set = {
  up: function() {$('.up').css('background-color', _config.upColor)},
  down : function() {$('.down').css('background-color', _config.downColor)}
};

if (true) {
  set.up();
}
```